# Segmentation Fault on dereferencing mapped memory

Tags: c++, linux, mmap

I'm running into an annoying issue where I cannot access memory obtained from `mmap` in any way without getting a segmentation fault.

The function I used to obtain the mapped memory looks like this.

```
   /**
   * Preconditions: filename must be verified as referencing a valid file.
   */
  char *IOUtils::memory_map_file(string const& filename, size_t length, int open_flags){
    int fd = open(filename.c_str(), open_flags | O_CREAT, 
                  S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
    int prot;
    if (open_flags == O_RDONLY)
      prot = PROT_READ;
    else
      prot = PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE;
    void *output = mmap(NULL, length, prot, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (output == (void *) -1){
      cerr << filename << ": " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
      _exit(2);
    }
    close(fd);
    return (char *)output;
  }
```

My main function looks like this.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  size_t input_length = IOUtils::file_size(argv[1]); //This works fine
  char *input_buffer = IOUtils::memory_map_file(argv[1], input_length,
    O_RDONLY); //This succeeds
  char *output_buffer = IOUtils::memory_map_file(argv[2], 2*input_length,
    O_RDWR); //This succeeds
  DomainParser parser(input_length, input_buffer, output_buffer);
  while(!parser.finished()){
    parser.write_entry();
  }
  mremap(output_buffer, 2*input_length, MREMAP_MAYMOVE, 
         parser.bytes_written());
  munmap(output_buffer, parser.bytes_written());
}
```

The parser's relevant code looks like this

```
void DomainParser::write_entry(void){
    char const *in = input(); //Gets position in input file
    char const *copy_up_to = end(); //Gets position at input EOF
    for(char const *it = in; it < copy_up_to; ++it){
        cerr << *it;   //SIGSEGV! 
        if(*it == '\n') break;
    }
    cerr << '\n';
    /* Do writes */
}
```

The program segfaults immediately upon `cerr << *it`. I have no idea why this would happen, considering all mapped memory is equipped with read permissions and is successfully allocated.

Edit: If anyone suspects the class is broken somewhere, here's the full source code.

```
using std::stringstream;
using std::string;

class DomainParser{
  size_t _input_offset;
  const size_t _input_length;
  size_t _output_offset;
  char const *input_buffer;
  char *output_buffer;

  char const *input(void){
    return input_buffer + _input_offset;
  }

  char *output(void){
    return output_buffer + _output_offset;
  }

  char const* end(void){
    return input_buffer + _input_length;
  }

  char const *find(char const *begin, char const *max, char c){
    while (*begin != c){
      cerr << *begin++;
    }
    cerr << c;
    return begin;
  }

public: 
  DomainParser(size_t length, char const *input, char *output) :
    _input_length(length), input_buffer(input), output_buffer(output)
  {}

  bool finished(void){
    return _input_offset == _input_length;
  }

  size_t bytes_written(void){
    return _output_offset;
  }

  size_t write_entry(void){
    if (finished()){
      return 0;  
    }
    char const *in = input();
    char const *copy_up_to = find(in, end(), '\n');
    size_t input_entry_length = copy_up_to - in;

    string s(in, copy_up_to);
    stringstream ss(s);
    string name, type, host;
    ss >> name >> type >> host;
    if (!ss){
      cerr << s << '\n';
      _input_offset += input_entry_length;
      return 0;
    }
    ss.str(""); ss.clear();
    ss << "{\"name\":\"" << name << "\"," <<
      "\"host\":\"" << host << "\"," <<
      "\"type\":\"" << type << "\"}\n";
    string entry = ss.str();
    std::memcpy(output(), entry.c_str(), entry.size());

    _input_offset += input_entry_length;
    _output_offset += entry.size();
    return entry.size();
  }
};
```

Comment: What has this to do with shared memory?? Probably an error with `char const *in = input();` And you don't show us what `input()` does.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie What kind of question is that? I'm getting a segfault when dereferencing mapped memory.  For reference, input() is defined as `{return input_buffer + _input_offset}`, where offset is initially 0, and the buffer is the same buffer returned from `mmap`.

Comment: You can easily check whether it is problem with mapping or not, just read first and last mapped buffer bytes right after retrieving it in `main` like this: `assert(0 < input_length); cerr << input_buffer[0] << input_buffer[input_length - 1];`

Comment: `int fd = open(filename.c_str(), open_flags | O_CREAT, ...`  O_CREAT doesn't make sense, here. Why don't you check `if (fd== -1)`?

Comment: It seems that I've gotten rusty on my C++ initialization basics. Primitive class variables are not zero-initialized by default, which caused the initial segfault. After fixing this, I instead get a bus error when trying to write to the output buffer. I suppose that's progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any initialization of `_input_offset`.

If you fix that, you will run into the problem that the output file is empty, so accessing any pages will trigger a `SIGBUS` signal.  You need to resize it using `ftruncate` to the intended size (probably to match the size of the mapping, but this depends on what you are trying to do).

Also not that `munmap` can be very expensive (especially on large systems), so memory-mapped I/O is only a win when the file sizes are quite large.